# flutter - application not wokring on a android emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, emulation

hi am getting this message whenever am starting my flutter application on a android stuido emulator
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
C:\Users\ad-admin.gradle\caches\transforms-3\acbce933e4b464a5224ed377a62db1f5\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\values\values.xml:5:4: Invalid  for given resource value.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 12s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution would be like that if you are working on the android studio:

```
go to “File” -> “Invalidate Caches/Restart” (below “Synchronize”)
select first option “Invalidate and Restart”
```

If it did not work, you can try to change your project location (path) and rebuild it again.

It can be emitted from different errors. For example, maybe it can be duplicate resources error, for example, if you put two images with the same name in the drawable folder, it can cause an error too.